# How to link "class" name in href of same html file?

Tags: html, css, class, tags, href

I want to link the project class into the nav item. How can I link the class name into the href?

##### code of nav item

```
<li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
</li>
```

##### code of projects

```
<div class="projects">
      <h4>--Projects--</h4>
       .....
</div>
```

both of the codes are in the same HTML file.

Comment: This seems a big vague, can you elaborate please? Do you mean an anchor link? That can be done with css ID's.

Comment: Yes. I want to link the `class="projects"` into the nav item `<a href="#"></a>` where both of them are written in the same html file.

Comment: not working with classes, only with an ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to obtain this behavior, you're going to have to use `IDs` instead of `classes`. `IDs` can only be used once per page. Now from what I understand you want the nav item to jump to a particular part of the page. In this example, you would give your `<a href="#projects"` to where you want your page to jump. So in this example, once you click the nav item "Projects" you will jump to the `div id="projects"` portion of the page.

```html
<li class="nav-item">
     <a href="#projects" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
</li>

I want to link the project class into the nav item. How can I link the class name into the href?

code of nav item
<li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
</li>
code of projects
<div id="projects">
      <h4>--Projects--</h4>
       .....
</div>
```

Comment: Your explanation is good, but the html can be clearer and concise.

Comment: @rawnewdlz That is his HTML, I changed only what was needed for it to work. Want OP to see it work in his application. I'd argue that the best way for them to understand the concept.

Comment: I'm in agreement with you in having OP see their html in action. My suggestion is to format it better, perhaps also include some filler text so when testing the snippet and clicking the link it would move somewhere down the page. The other answer posted has the right idea because it's OP's html but also what it could potentially look like altogether. I feel like their html example is helpful, but you are also helpful in explaining further how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tags to scroll to an element using IDs, like `<a href="#id-of-target-element">`. See example below.

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav justify-content-center">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h1>This is a filler container</h1>
  <p>The purpose of this container is to take up space between the navbar and the element to which you want to scroll. Using an href to scroll to a specific element is called "Anchor Tags." You can google it and read more about it, but it's a pretty easy concept. Just put <code>&lt;a href="#element-id"&gt;Some Text&lt;/a&gt;</code>.
  <br><br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vehicula, nisl quis tincidunt cursus, lectus velit facilisis erat, a lacinia eros diam quis massa. Donec pellentesque euismod lacus a egestas. Duis non orci purus. Phasellus at felis et nunc sodales placerat vulputate id ex. Nunc consequat varius dolor, nec bibendum ligula fermentum vel. Morbi aliquam eu turpis sit amet molestie. Nulla luctus eu enim a porta. In maximus et nibh sed accumsan.
  <br><br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vehicula, nisl quis tincidunt cursus, lectus velit facilisis erat, a lacinia eros diam quis massa. Donec pellentesque euismod lacus a egestas. Duis non orci purus. Phasellus at felis et nunc sodales placerat vulputate id ex. Nunc consequat varius dolor, nec bibendum ligula fermentum vel. Morbi aliquam eu turpis sit amet molestie. Nulla luctus eu enim a porta. In maximus et nibh sed accumsan.
  <br><br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vehicula, nisl quis tincidunt cursus, lectus velit facilisis erat, a lacinia eros diam quis massa. Donec pellentesque euismod lacus a egestas. Duis non orci purus. Phasellus at felis et nunc sodales placerat vulputate id ex. Nunc consequat varius dolor, nec bibendum ligula fermentum vel. Morbi aliquam eu turpis sit amet molestie. Nulla luctus eu enim a porta. In maximus et nibh sed accumsan.</p>
</div>

<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <div class="projects" id="projects">
    <h4>Projects</h4>
    <p>This is the container you want to scroll to.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>This is another filler container</h1>
  <p>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vehicula, nisl quis tincidunt cursus, lectus velit facilisis erat, a lacinia eros diam quis massa. Donec pellentesque euismod lacus a egestas. Duis non orci purus. Phasellus at felis et nunc sodales placerat vulputate id ex. Nunc consequat varius dolor, nec bibendum ligula fermentum vel. Morbi aliquam eu turpis sit amet molestie. Nulla luctus eu enim a porta. In maximus et nibh sed accumsan.</p>
</div>
```